# iMac screen has vertical lines

Tags: display, imac

So my iMac screen, all of a sudden, gets lines and starts flickering but sometimes it’s back to normal.

What’s happening ?

iMac late 2013 A1418 EMC 2638

[image]

Comment: Either the graphics card or the connecting cable is dying. Either way, you need a repair shop.

Comment: To narrow down the cause you can connect the iMac to an external monitor and see if the image still has lines etc. If it does you know its the GPU. If it doesn't, then it's either the internal display or the cable connecting it.

Comment: Hi, welcome here! check these questions, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196870/what-causes-5-pink-bars-on-27-imac-2011 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107440/macbook-pro-screen-glitches-after-fall?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98569/coloured-vertical-lines-on-screen?rq=1 There are quite a lot about iMac too, mostly limited to comments only, no answers. Use tag based search. ping me by @ankiiiiiii. See side bar for titles of linked questions. [tour] when you're free :)